# Spotify Android development: Premium users

Tags: android, spotify, libspotify

If I have an Spotify account and I want develop an Android app with my tracklists, the users who listen this songs need to be a premium users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will - libspotify is a Premium-only feature.